# Is it possible to use/convert a 3-legged token on Autodesk Forge Object Storage Service (OSS)?

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I know Autodesk Forge  "Object Storage Service" (OSS) requires a 2-legged security token...
I already use a 3-legged token to access Forge "Project Service" and "Data Service" APIs: is it possible to convert or request a 2-legged token from a 3-legged token?
If you try to use a 3-legged token with OSS you get a invalid token error.

I would like to avoid using two different authentication at the same time...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately token exchange is not possible - I checked the [oAuth 2.0 specification](https://oauth.net/2/), and I don't think the flow you describe is a valid flow anyway. Remember 2 legged is for application credentials, whereas 3 legged is to access a specific user content.

Answer (score 0):

No, a 2-legged token gives you the access to developer's resources. A 3-legged token gives you access to the logged in user's resources. They are not designed to be interchangeable.